# Django - After overriding the base_site.html, i was unable to publish my post and causing CSRF error

Tags: html, css, django, overriding, csrf

Here is my code for base_site.html

```
{% extends "admin/base.html" %}
{% load static %}
{% block title %}{% if subtitle %}{{ subtitle }} | {% endif %}{{ title }} | 
{{ site_title|default:_('Admin') }}
{% endblock %}
{% block extrastyle %}
<style type="text/css">
    #branding h1{
        color: #fff !important;
    }
    #branding h1 a:link, #branding h1 a:visited {
        color: #fff !important;
    }
    .submit-row input{
        background-color: #00b388;
    }
    #header {
        background-color: #000000;
        color: #fff !important;
    }
    .module caption{
        background-color: #00b388;
    }
    div.breadcrumbs {
        background: #00b388;
    }
    .object-tools a.addlink{
        background-color: #00b388;
    }
    input[type=submit].default, .submit-row input.default{
        background-color: #00b388;
    }
</style>
{% endblock %}
{% block branding %}
<form  method="post">{% csrf_token %}
<h1 id="site-name"><a href="{% url 'admin:index' %}"><img src="{% static 'img/logo.PNG' %}" height="30px" /></a></h1>
{% endblock %}
{% block nav-global %}
{% endblock %}

    unfortunately i have added the <form> tag in the above code, just to over come with CSRF issue and it does.
    unfortunately, this approach gives me another error,
```

i.e, i have 3 file fields in my Model, and even though, i have mentioned the files during the upload and when i hit submit, it is not working and keep showing me This field is required error.

```
    I am new to Django and your response helps me great.
    versions:-
    Django - 2.2
    python - 3.6.2
```

Comment: Can you show the full traceback for your error?

Comment: Your form tag is not closed. is it normal ?

Comment: @EricMartin If i close the form tag, unfortunately i am seeing 403 forbidden error..

Comment: do you have a stacktrace with the 403 ?

Comment: Hi @EricMartin after closing the <form> tag, the issue get fixed. Thanks a ton

Comment: Nice ! can you accept my answer below ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to close the form tag :

```
<form  method="post">{% csrf_token %}
</form>
<h1 id="site-name"><a href="{% url 'admin:index' %}"><img src="{% static 'img/logo.PNG' %}" height="30px" /></a></h1>
{% endblock %}
{% block nav-global %}
{% endblock %}
```